# Getting empty object when sharing lookalike audience with adaccount - Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-custom-audience

Making a `POST` request to share Custom Facebook Audience
`POST {custom_audience_id}/adaccounts?adaccounts=[<ad_account_id>]&relationship_type=[<relationship_type>]` returns the object as per the official documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/share-custom-audiences)

```
{  
    success: bool,
    sharing_data : [
     {         
       "ad_acct_id": id
       "business_id": id
       "audience_share_status" : string
       "errors" : list<string>
     },
     ...
    ]
}
```

When trying to share the created lookalike audience the sharing is successful but the `sharing_data` object comes as an empty list `[]` This means that I need to check the sharing status for this particular audience with a separate `GET` call to `{audience_id}/shared_account_info`. Which seems to have different responses for custom audiences and for lookalike audiences.

- I tried to find any documentation explaining this logic to no success. I am using `https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/` version of graph api
- I tried to send `fields` with POST requests but still get the empty list

Is there any workaround or this is the only way to do it?

The code I am using:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)
method = 'POST'
endpoint = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/{audience_id}/adaccounts'
params = {'adaccounts': str(partner_ad_account_id),
          'relationship_type': ['Audience Info Provider', 'Information Manager']}
response = AdAccount(adaccount_id).get_api_assured().call(
                method,
                endpoint,
                params=params
            )
```